# Unity3D Game: deal with constants within one file

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, unity-game-engine

I need to group all my constants into one file and show them on the inspector. Here's what i've tried:

1. `#define` constants

   ```
   #define speed 10.0f
   #define hp 3
   ```

   This doesn't work, no matter where i put them, Error:

   > Cannot define or undefine preprocessor symbols after first token in file
2. Use static

   ```
   public static readonly float speed = 10.0f;
   public static readonly int hp = 3;
   ```

   It works, but when i attach it to the main camera, the constants do not show up in the inspector window. Well now I know inspector doesn't support static field.
3. Use Singleton as suggested

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class GameConfig : MonoBehaviour {


   private static GameConfig instance;

   public GameConfig() 
   {
       if (instance != null) 
       {
           Debug.LogError("GameConfig Warning: unable to create multiple instances");
       }
       instance = this;
   }

   public static GameConfig Instance 
   {
       get
       {
           if (instance == null) 
           {
               Debug.Log("GameConfig: Creating an instance");
               new GameConfig();
           }
           return instance;
       }
   }
   ```

   Now if I add:

   ```
   public float speed = 10.0f;
   ```

   the GameConfig.Instance.speed IS accessible, but the mono editor does not pop out auto completion. And it get this message:

   > CompareBaseObjects  can only be called from the main thread.
   >   Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
   >   Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

   If I try:

   ```
   public float speed = 10.0f;
   public float Speed {get {return speed;}}
   ```

   I get the same message.

But the game can still work, and variables show on inspector correctly. 
Note: Even if i fix it, is there any other ways to do? since it seems redundant to write a constants with 2 names (property + field) and tedious work.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use singleton in a gameObject in Unity by C#, you should not use the constructor of sub class(GameConfig), but create a GameObject and then add the needed component to it. Like this:

```
private static GameConfig _instance = null;
public static GameConfig instance 
{
    get {
        if (!_instance) {
            //check if an GameConfig is already in the scene
            _instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameConfig)) as GameConfig;

            //nope create one
        if (!_instance) {
            var obj = new GameObject("GameConfig");
            DontDestroyOnLoad(obj);
            _instance = obj.AddComponent<GameConfig>();
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

By the way, in your method-2, you can get things done by setting up an inspect UI by your self. Build up a custom editor for GameConfig and the add things you want to inspect. Refer to [CustomEditor attribute](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CustomEditor.html) and [Editor.OnInspectorGUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Editor.OnInspectorGUI.html) for more information. If you don't know how to customize an inspector or how to extend the default editor, you can find some useful guides in the [Extending Editor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/gui-ExtendingEditor.html) in Unity's site (Custom Inspectors section may be suit for you).

Comment: UnityException: You are not allowed to call this function when declaring a variable.
Move it to the line after without a variable declaration.
If you are using C# don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, Instead move initialization to the Awake or Start function.
UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType (System.Type type)

Comment: Hi, I directly use if(null) create instance and works now. but the mono editor still does not pop out auto completion

Comment: autocomplete is okay now after deleting some system cache files.

Comment: That's great! Maybe try to clicking sync with mono in the asset menu will be also solve the auto completion issue.